# Terraform aws_cloudformation_stack AlreadyExistsException

Tags: jenkins, aws-cloudformation, terraform

When running Terraform to execute a Cloudformation stack via the resouce aws_cloudformation_stack, the error "AlreadyExistsException" appears when running against a stack that already exists.

Is it possible to skip over the stack when it exists rather and continue with other resource deployments, rather than failing the entire deployment?

Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The answer to your question as it stands is no. But if you provided more context here (such as what you're trying to do and how and why Terraform is unaware of the existing CloudFormation stack) then you might get a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback - the issue was where in main.tf multiple instances of a module were being generated, and the stack name for two of these instances was identical. Once this was fixed, Terraform was able to create / amend the Cloudformation stacks.